# Retrieve Admin product grid columns from an helper

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, grid, column, product-grid

I would like to get all the columns infos of the product grid columns from my own helper.

I tried (among others) with the following code :

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
$gridBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_grid');
```

If I log then `$gridBlock->debug()`, I obtain

```
Array
(
    [row_click_callback] => openGridRow
    [id] => productGrid
    [use_ajax] => 1
    [type] => adminhtml/catalog_product_grid
)
```

but the return of `$gridBlock->getColumns()` is an empty array.

In other words, I'm trying to simulate the creation of the product grid in order to get its columns informations.

Any ideas on how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

with the help of Marius answer, I succeed with the following code :

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
$gridBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_grid')->setTemplate('');
$gridBlock->toHtml();
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

Then `$gridBlock->getColumns()` returns what I was expecting.

Note that the emulating part may be unnecessary if you run this code from the admin part. So, it should work with this :

```
$gridBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_grid')->setTemplate('');
$gridBlock->toHtml();
```

**Edit 1** : I updated my answer as I just saw that there was an error in the `system.log` : `CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/widget/grid.phtml`. In fact, I should pass a second parameter (`Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML`) in the `startEnvironmentEmulation` method to ensure that design will be build from the admihtml area. But when I do that, I get again the fatal error : `PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting`. So, I made it work without error by setting a "fake" template : `$gridBlock->setTemplate('page/head.phtml')`. I hope I will find a cleaner way to do that and I will edit my answer in this case.

**Edit 2** : Well, it seems the error `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached` I have when I don't change the template is due to some infinite loop that begins in the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml` (especially with the massaction part). If I comment this part, it works with just a

```
$gridBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/catalog_product_grid');
$gridBlock->toHtml();
```

Moreover, as I launch this code from the admin area, I can even delete all the `$appEmulation` part. I don't remove it from my answer as it can be usefull for someone who wants to launch it from the frontend.

Finally, to be "cleaner", instead of calling the `page/head.html`, I will create my own "fake" template and call it. I didn't find any observer that allow me to remove the massaction block properly.

**Edit 3** : With a `setTemplate('')`, it works too without any error. I update my answer with this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The columns property is not populated until you call `the toHtml` method of the block.
The method `_prepareColumns`, the one that builds the columns is called in the `_prepareGrid` method that is called in `_beforeToHtml` that is called in `toHtml`.

So you can try

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
$gridBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_grid');
$gridBlock->toHtml();
$columns = $grid->getColumns();
```

but there is a chance you will get errors if you are out of context.
Anyway... It's cheap to try it.

Comment: Thanks @Marius, you pushed me on the right way. I fact I've already seen that the only public method I could call was the `toHtml` method. But, as you say, I gave up because there was error (some weird `PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!` on server side). Following your comment "you will get errors if you are out of context", I tried with some `$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');` workaround; I will post my answer but yours was very usefull.